# Problem with ImageField in GridView

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

I've got a GridView which loads data from a DataTable. One of the columns in the DataTable is called 'Icon', and stores small icons which are .png files. It must be noted that the fields are all generated at run-time.

What I've done to be able to load the images in the GridView, is that I've created an ImageField through the format wizard on the GridView, and I've selected the 'Icon' field from the DataTable as the DataImageUrlField. The images load in this manually generated new column, however the 'Icon' column of the DataTable is still displayed in the GridView. Whenever I try hiding this column, the ImageField column is hidden too.

What can I do to just display the ImageField column?

Thanks

Comment: this is already answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983512/how-to-have-one-of-the-column-in-gridview-to-be-an-image

Answer (score 0):

Set `AutoGenerateColumns="false"` for GridView.