# how to have one of the column in gridview to be an image?

Tags: asp.net, image, gridview, code-behind

I have a gridview that gets created in codebehind.

In the below code, I would like to have 3rd column to be some image (Example: PDF icon or similar).

I am thinking `Type.GetType` needs to be changed for column named "Image"??

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
GridView gview = new GridView();
DataRow dr;
DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("Description", Type.GetType("System.String"));
dt.Columns.Add(dc);
dc = new DataColumn("Image", Type.GetType("System.String"));
dt.Columns.Add(dc);
dc = new DataColumn("Size (MB)", Type.GetType("System.String"));
dt.Columns.Add(dc);
{
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["Description"] = item["Name"];
    dr["Size (MB)"] = item["Size"];
    dr["Image"] = "pdf.gif"; // put complete reference here,
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
gview.DataSource = dt;
gview.DataBind();
Controls.Add(gview);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just store the image URL in the DataTable rather than the actual image. Then, use a `TemplateField` in your GridView and put an Image in the `ItemTemplate`:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImageUrlColumn") %>' ... />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

You can also use an `ImageField`:

```
<asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="ImageNameColumn" DataImageUrlFormatString="/images/{0}"></asp:ImageField>
```

**EDIT**

When declaring columns, try this instead:

```
dt.Columns.Add("Image", typeof(string));
```

And to set the value of the image column, try this:

```
dr.SetField<string>("Image", "img.png");
```

Comment: I could not follow completely. Where do I need to define ImageUrlColumn? Is it the column name I am defining in codebehind?

Comment: Instead of trying to store an image in the DataTable, just store the path to the image, i.e. `/images/somepic.png`. The `ImageUrlColumn` is only intended to demonstrate the idea.

Comment: I am storing the path only (as posted in first post) and the path will have some folder like you mentioned. I am still not getting why I need to have the templatefield/itemfield that you mentioned and if required where to associate it in the gridview. please clarify. thanks

Comment: You need the template field to display the image in the GridView. You can also use an `ImageField` too, if you'd rather. See edited answer for how to use an `ImageField`.

Comment: so in ASPX I put <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="ImageNameColumn" DataImageUrlFormatString="/images/pdf.png"></asp:ImageField> and then in code behind I associate dr["Image"] = this.ImageNameColumn;  Did I follow correctly?

Comment: `DataImageUrlFormatString` is expecting a format string, not an actual image name. If you're storing the whole path in the datacolumn, you probably don't even need to use the `DataImageUrlFormatString`.

Comment: I had tried with dr["Image"] = "\images\pdf.gif" but it is giving error. I thought it could be because of of TYPE defination in         "dc = new DataColumn("Image", Type.GetType("System.String"))"? I will be hardcoding the image and hence I don't think it is necessary to use temlatefield or imagefield?  Please suggest.

Comment: "dr.SetField<string>("Image", "img.png")" gives error as there is no SetField available for "dr".

Comment: What version of ASP.NET are you using? You must be using 2.0 or earlier, huh?

Comment: Visual studio shows .NET framework version 3.5 SP1. Seems the site is running ASP.NET as 2.0.50727

Comment: Go into the properties of your project and change the target framework to 3.5 or above and my suggestion should work.

Comment: Changed ther framework and tested the code. No errors but the Image column in the grid shows "img.png" but not the actual image. I want it to show the actual image under IMAGE column in the grid. Please suggest

Comment: I didn't add this line in ASPX page "<asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="ImageNameColumn" DataImageUrlFormatString="/images/{0}"></asp:ImageField>"... Let me know if it needs to be added. I don't think it is required.

Comment: You're going to have to use either a `TemplateField` or an `ImageField` to display your image in the GridView. Not sure what more I can say really... everything you need is in the answer.

Comment: Considering the suggested changes made in the aspx.cs, what should be the equivalent changes required in aspx? The column used in the grid is named "Image". I tried this and no success. <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="ImageNameColumn" ></asp:ImageField>.

Answer (score 0):

In grid view put command field column like the following

`<asp:CommandField runat="server"  ShowDeleteButton="true" ButtonType="Image" DeleteImageUrl="images/delete.png" ></asp:CommandField>`

set the gridview property like the following

AutoGenerateDeleteButton="false"

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to enable in your DataGrid the RowDataBound Event. Then set in the event the wire up for each new row to your image.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowWEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //Setup in your image column index. By Example setting 0
        e.Row.Cells[0].Text=Server.HtmlDecode(@"<img src=""./Images/pdf.gif"" />");
    }
}
```