# ASP.Net GridView show image

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, data-binding

Is it possible to show an image in GridView in `AutoGenerateColumns` mode? I've tryed this one

```
    private void LoadEventLog(string servicesName)
    {
        var bmp = new Bitmap(32, 32);
        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            g.Clear(Color.Purple);
        }
        var logs = ServiceHelper.GetEventLogs(servicesName)
            .Select(x => new {x.MachineName, x.TimeGenerated, Category = GetCategory(x.Category), x.Message, Img=bmp })
            .Take(100)
            .ToArray(); //
        ServicesGrid.DataSource = logs;
        ServicesGrid.DataBind();
    }
```

aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="ServicesGrid" OnRowDataBound="ServicesGrid_OnItemDataBound" 
     OnPageIndexChanging="ServicesGrid_OnPageIndexChanging"
     AutoGenerateColumns="true" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" />
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the gridview supports bitmaps for autogeneratecolumns. Plus, I'm pretty sure that the images are not stored in your logo column. It looks like it just stores the type.

One solution would be to store the base64 representation of your image or URL, and then bind manually the column.

From this link (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx):

> Instead of letting the GridView control automatically generate the
>   column fields, you can manually define the column fields by setting
>   the AutoGenerateColumns property to false and then creating a custom
>   Columns collection. In addition to bound column fields, you can also
>   display a button column field, a check box column field, a command
>   field, a hyperlink column field, **an image field**, or a column field
>   **based on your own custom-defined template**.

Possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7983647/375304