# Bitmap in datasource not showing in asp .net Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, bitmap

I have a DataTable I'm populating in code, which I add to a DataSet, which is then used to fill a GridView. 
This works OK apart from a bitmap column I've just added; and I can't see what I'm missing. My guess is I'm going about this completely wrong as it's my first dabble with website code :)

Here's the page code for the grid - you can see I'm not specifying individual columns, they just come automatically from the DataSet.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
                </asp:ScriptManager>
                <asp:GridView ID="gridTicketsByGroup" runat="server" CaptionAlign="Left" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="TicketsByGroupDatasource" Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Font-Names="Verdana">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" Font-Size="Medium" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
                </asp:GridView>
                <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="TicketsByGroupDatasource" runat="server" SelectMethod="ShowTicketsByGroupReport" TypeName="PhoneMonitor.GroupReport"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
                <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
                </asp:Timer>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The select method I have just returns the DataSet containing the DataTable:

```
returnedDataSet.Tables.Add(dataRetriever.TicketsByGroupTable);
return returnedDataSet;
```

For testing, I've added one bitmap so far. The whole column simply doesn't show though. Column is added like this:

```
TicketsByGroupTable.Columns.Add("Logo", typeof(Bitmap));
row[0] = LoadIcon(rowName);

 private Bitmap LoadIcon(string ProductName)
        {
            string fileName = "";
            switch (ProductName)
            {
                case "Test":
                    fileName = "PhoneMonitor.Icons.Test.png";
                    break;
            }
            if (fileName != "")
            {
                System.Reflection.Assembly thisAss = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
                Bitmap b = new Bitmap(thisAss.GetManifestResourceStream(fileName));
                return b;
            }
            else return null;
        }
```

If I preview the table it looks like it's loaded OK:

[image: Preview]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the gridview supports bitmaps for autogeneratecolumns. Plus, I'm pretty sure that the images are not stored in your logo column. It looks like it just stores the type.

One solution would be to store the base64 representation of your image or URL, and then bind manually the column.

**EDIT:** from this link (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx):

> Instead of letting the GridView control automatically generate the
>   column fields, you can manually define the column fields by setting
>   the AutoGenerateColumns property to false and then creating a custom
>   Columns collection. In addition to bound column fields, you can also
>   display a button column field, a check box column field, a command
>   field, a hyperlink column field, **an image field**, or a column field
>   **based on your own custom-defined template**.

Possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7983647/375304

Comment: Hmm, that may be easier then; if I unbind the columns and just set the image field manually to the url of the file or something...

Comment: That would be much easier, yes, and it is a common practice (use URLs rather than objects for images).
It also reduces memory usage and will speed up the databinding of your grid.

Comment: Hurrah. Manual columns with the first one like this: <asp:ImageField dataimageurlfield="Logo" />  works. Thanks!