# C# How to display image dynamically into gridview from webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have this code below which is me invoking a REST web service to populate my gridview. The thing that i'm current trying to accomplish is to use the `image` URL i'm getting from the api to display the image onto my gridview and not just the link. Is there any easy way to accomplish this? Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

```
public partial class Book : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public class Result
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string subtitle { get; set; }
        public string price { get; set; }
        public string image { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
    }

    public class SearchList
    {
        public int resultCount;
        public Result[] books;
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string searchTerm = TextBox1.Text;
        var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create
        ("https://api.itbook.store/1.0/search/" + Server.UrlEncode(searchTerm));
        var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
        if (webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
            string resString = sr.ReadToEnd();
            SearchList list = json.Deserialize<SearchList>(resString);
            GridView1.DataSource = list.books;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        else
            Label1.Text = "Invalid Response";
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to have one of the column in gridview to be an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983512/how-to-have-one-of-the-column-in-gridview-to-be-an-image)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are binding a Class list to the GridView. I would recommend using a Stronly Typed GridView with `ItemTemplate`. You have to make sure that the `ItemType` property points to your class.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ItemType="YourNameSpace.Result">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title">
            <ItemTemplate>

                <%# Item.title  %>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">
            <ItemTemplate>

                <img src="<%# Item.url  %>" />

                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Item.url %>' />

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```